# Logic error involving area of circle

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, area, subroutine

In python, don't know why, it some kind of logic error, as in it's not the right number, where i'm supposed to create a algorithm which calculate area of a circle from the radius.

[My python code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TTfwP.png)

Comment: why not writing down your code ? You should search for geometry formula (obvisouly wrong)

Comment: You can post your code in your question. Posting an image is just wrong... Besides that you should look up the equations and/or take a look at basic math books. You seem to have problems with transforming equations.

Comment: you assign to `area` the value of the radius, and assign the name `radius` to a function that outputs the circumference... why? why?!? my OCD can't handle this

Answer (score 1):

```
math.sqrt()
```

means calculate Square Root Calculations(√). 
You just need

```
r * r
```

to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
area = (22/7)((r)**2)
```

hope it helps .

Comment: please don't use `22/7`, it's a really bad approximation for `pi`, at least with writing `3.142` explicitly he knows his error range. plus he already did `import math`, he could actually use `math.pi`

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate area of circle without defining any function.

Try this:

```
pi = 3.142
r = float(input("enter your radius of circle: "))

Area = pi * r * r

print("Area of the circle is: ", area)
```

Answer (score 0):

The Below is to Find the radius and circumference of circle

```
# Name
Name = raw_input("Enter Your Name: ")

# Give area for the circle
Area = input("Enter Area of the circle: ")

PI = 3.14

# Calculation of radius and circumference
R = (Area / PI )**0.5
C = (2 * PI * R)

print "Area of the Circle = %.2f"%Area 
print "Radius of Circle = %.2f"%R
print "Circumference of Circle = %.2f"%C
```

Comment: Please note the conventions for formatting [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 0):

```
def computeArea(val):
    area=pi*(val**2)
    return area
pi=3.14
inputText=input("does the question give a diameter(d) or radius(r)")
if inputText=='r':
    radius=int(input("what is the radius"))
    print(f"area of the circle is {computeArea(radius)}")
elif inputText=='d':
    D=int(input("what is the diameter"))
    r=(D/2)
    area=computeArea(r)
    print(f"area of the circle is {computeArea(r)}")
else:
    print("You entered an incorrect value you can either type r for radius or d for diameter")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).